# Is Apache Kafka able to handle transactions?

Tags: java, transactions, apache-kafka

we plan to use Kafka as a central component in our data warehouse given that the producer is able to handle transactions (in short: rollbacks and commits).

When googling *Kafka + Transactions* I find a lot of theoretical thoughts about the possibility of how Kafka *could* handle transactions but at the moment I do not see any function in the java API that supports commits and rollbacks for the *producer*.

Has anybody made some experiences with transactions and Kafka and can give me an hint?

Comment: could you be bit more specific on producer part? what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: Simply said: I want to push a message to a topic via the Java producer API and see if it works. If id worked I'd like to commit the message to the topic. Similar to in JMS oder XA in common relational database systems.

Comment: "See if it works" -- the producer API can callback with success or failure. That should be enough for data warehousing: if Kafka is not your system of record, then you can always *retry* sending to Kafka.  Or can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is basically called transactional messaging in Kafka where producers are capable of creating session (aka transactional session) and send messages within the sessions. Hence it can choose to either commit / abort the transaction.

[Source]: Please read the [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Transactional+Messaging+in+Kafka) for details

Comment: Hi, yes I've seen the wiki but this is - as far as I can judge it - only a proposal for a future implementation. My question is if it is already possible with the current release to handle transactional sessions.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>No; Kafka does not support transactions.</strike>

You can get certainty that a message has been produced to a partition, but once produced you are not able to rollback that message.

Since version 0.11.0 Apache Kafka supports transactions: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Transactional+Messaging+in+Kafka

Comment: Only theoretical things are there, no mention of how to implement that in code.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, from the last version 0.11.0.0 transactions are supported. See [Guarantee unique global transaction for Kafka Producers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064622/guarantee-unique-global-transaction-for-kafka-producers/45071220#45071220)